# system center configuration manager SUP and DP in the same box

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, sccm-2012, system-center, update

I 've got system center configuration manage installed and Software update point and distrbution point are in the same server .
after getting Updates from Microsoft and deploying them I understood that it's coping Updates into Distribution point content library.that's ok.But It is using double disk space .
Is there any way to distribute Updates without coping them into Distribution point?and using less disk space?
thanx

Comment: is't  there any answer ?

Comment: Just FYI: try not to rush people who spend their precious free time drumming up an answer for fake Internet points.

Answer (score 2):

SCCM is always gonna copy double disk space when copying from a scratch directory to a DP, I don't think there's a way around this. If you want to conserve space on the server, consider having the clients download directly from MS if your bandwidth can handle it, or setting your scratch directory off the server. Otherwise,  the only real solution is more storage.